# Android long key press

Tags: android

I need to generate/trigger a long key press event of a button in Android.

Any help regrading this?

Answer (score 39):

From Android 2.0, Activity contains the method

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

For exemple, a long key press on the back button would be :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        // do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Take a look at [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).

Comment: You likely need start tracking the event in the onKeyPress handler.  See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222181/can-you-intercept-the-long-press-on-menu

Comment: Why onKeyLongPress() vs. onLongPress()?

Comment: Both work but onKeyLongPress is simpler and faster to implement. You can use it directly inside your view. OnLongPress is part of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener. You will have to code the whole gestures detector/listener thing. If you already have one, sure, you can use it.

Comment: Note that onLongKeyPress doesn't work for KEYCODE_BACK, regardless of whether I call event.startTracking() in onKeyDown...

Comment: @Pierre-LucPaour : you have to call startTracking AND return true from onKeyDown as specified in the doc : "_Note that in order to receive this callback, someone in the event change must return true from onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) and call startTracking() on the event._"

Comment: @rockeye: that's what I'm doing. My onLongKeyPress method isn't getting called (on ICS, with a virtual back key). I noticed that with a physical back key, my views are getting repeating onKey events when I keep pressing on the key, but with a virtual key, I get only a down and an up event, that may explain it.

Answer (score -6):

You can set Long key press on button like:

```
btnNext.setLongClickable(true);
btnNext.setOnLongClickListener(l)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I think, this will enable long click on button and set a listener for it.

What i want is that for example key A(keydown event of a key) is pressed for some time.

Comment: In your listener method before executing any code, put Thread.sleep(2000);
It may help you.