# Can you intercept the long press on menu?

Tags: android

I'm using what should be pretty simple code, but it just doesn't want to work. Does the OS block intercepting this?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
    {
    longOptionPress = true;
    openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must call `startTracking()` on the event from the normal `onKeyPress()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

See also [a question I asked and answered some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681743/how-to-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-ever-appearing-in-my-activity/4681762#4681762).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and link... that answered the followup question of the regular menu not launching.

Comment: The problem now is that you don't get single click on the menu button. How do you avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is ListView, You need to use `onCreateContextMenu`.

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
```