# Long pressing menu button closes dialog on Android 2.3

Tags: android-layout, android-view, android

We created an android library which is working with dialogs. After testing it on a Samsung Galaxy S1 Plus I9005 with Android 2.3.6 we experienced, that a long press on the devices menu button closes the active dialog immediately. I do not even know the purpose of long-pressing that button. 
For someone who does not know the device, this picture should show you what i mean:
[image: Samsung Galaxy S1]

The problem does not occur on devices running on Android 4.x. I tested it on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2 and even a Galaxy S1 with a Android 4.0.3 Custom ROM - no problem.

To suppress closing the dialog, i tried to override the `onKeyDown`, `onKeyUp`, `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and other methods which seemed to be relevant, but non of them brought success or any valuable information. The same happened when i tried to debug into those methods, because the dialog was gone before the debugger reached any method i can override.

The dialogs are created by using the following way:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final int pId) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (pId) {
        case LOADING_DIALOG:
            dialog = DialogCreator.createLoadingDialog(MyActivity.this));
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }
    super.onCreateDialog(pId);
    return dialog;
}
```

The `DialogCreator` is just creating an AlertDialog by using:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(pContext).create();
```

To prevent the dialog from being canceled I added:

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Anybody an idea why this is closing the dialog?

*edit*

While being on the 'Desktop' the long press on the menu button starts a Google search.

Comment: is this only closing the dialog or did Your app crash by pressing menu button?

Comment: just closing the dialog

Comment: For capturing the long press of menu button check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222181/can-you-intercept-the-long-press-on-menu) out. I tried with a 2.3.6 device and it seems to be working.

Comment: Capturing the long press is not the issue, because the dialog is already gone at that moment. How to prevent from closing the dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of [@QQQestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746091/1307690) has helped me solve this problem. You should use `OnKeyListener` to intercept menu button long click event.

**EDIT**

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
 return true; // Pretend we processed it
} else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
 return true; // Pretend we processed it
}
```

Comment: @DanielVermaasen On different vendors it may have different keys event try to catch them via debug and then handle them in your code. A have add code to ansver.

Comment: I have face same issue and get solved by your code for Samsung Galaxy Y android 2.3.6 OS.