# Android listen for backbutton longclick

Tags: android, onclick, back-button, onlongclicklistener

I am overriding the backbutton with a onBackPressed() function

how do I also detect long clicks on the backbutton? Is there an equivalent of @Override onBackLongPressed() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you (Check the first comment) - [Android long key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403465/android-long-key-press)

Comment: ah, I will just need the keyCode

Comment: The keycode is KEYCODE_BACK, by the way. As repeated a few times, now.

Answer (score 2):

From Android 2.0, Activity contains the method

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

For exemple, a long key press on the back button would be :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        // do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check "Story 2" [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html). There's not a shortcut for it like there is onBackPressed().

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use [onKeyLongPress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyLongPress%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) and handle the KEYCODE_BACK event yourself.