# Android long press system back button listener

Tags: android, events, back, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I want to add a listener for when the android system back button is long pressed i.e. a long press version of `Activity.onBackPressed`

This only needs to work when my app is visible.

Chrome shows the history menu when back is long pressed so it must be possible but can't find a hook for it. Thanks

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930950/8596924

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try overriding the `onKeyLongPress` method inside your `Activity`.

```java
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        System.out.println("Back button long pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Back buttons don't create key events.

Comment: I tested it on a sample app and it did work perfectly fine though.

Comment: Before Android 10, onKeyLongPress can catch back event in pressing the back button. But after Android 10, onKeyLongPress can not catch back gesture from edge to edge

Answer (score 1):

You can look at how firefox implement the Long Back Press.

https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mozilla/fenix/HomeActivity.kt

they implement it using both onKeyDown/onKeyUp and onKeyLongPress.

the reason both are used is because

> Android N and Huawei devices have broken onKeyLongPress events for the
> back button, so we instead implement the long press behavior ourselves
>
> - For short presses, we cancel the callback in onKeyUp
> - For long presses, the normal keyPress is marked as cancelled, hence won't be handled elsewhere   (but Android still provides the haptic
>   feedback), and the long press action is run

Below is their implementation.

```
// See onKeyDown for why this is necessary
private var backLongPressJob: Job? = null

private fun shouldUseCustomBackLongPress(): Boolean {
    val isAndroidN =
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1
    // Huawei devices seem to have problems with onKeyLongPress
    // See https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/13498
    val isHuawei = Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("huawei", ignoreCase = true)
    return isAndroidN || isHuawei
}

private fun handleBackLongPress(): Boolean {
    supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.forEach {
        if (it is OnBackLongPressedListener && it.onBackLongPressed()) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

final override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    // Inspired by https://searchfox.org/mozilla-esr68/source/mobile/android/base/java/org/mozilla/gecko/BrowserApp.java#584-613
    // Android N and Huawei devices have broken onKeyLongPress events for the back button, so we
    // instead implement the long press behavior ourselves
    // - For short presses, we cancel the callback in onKeyUp
    // - For long presses, the normal keypress is marked as cancelled, hence won't be handled elsewhere
    //   (but Android still provides the haptic feedback), and the long press action is run
    if (shouldUseCustomBackLongPress() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        backLongPressJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout().toLong())
            handleBackLongPress()
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}

final override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (shouldUseCustomBackLongPress() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        backLongPressJob?.cancel()
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
}

final override fun onKeyLongPress(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    // onKeyLongPress is broken in Android N so we don't handle back button long presses here
    // for N. The version check ensures we don't handle back button long presses twice.
    if (!shouldUseCustomBackLongPress() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return handleBackLongPress()
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope below idea works!!!

Add below code in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //This event will be triggered after 1 second. 
        //In case if you move out of KEYCODE_BACK, onKeyUp event will be triggered and this event will be cancelled 
        handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000); 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

handler code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i("Activity", "Long press detected").
       //Add your code
    }
};
```